# Actionbar text change while navigating screens

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am working with `ActionBar` in my application. But while I am navigating between screens in my application then after some time the text of `ActionBar` is not readable(please see attached screen).

I am not able to understand how can I resolved this. If anyone has any way to resolved this issue than please share here.

Thanks in advance.!!

My code is:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.search_icon));
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.topbar_bg));
mTitle = getTitle();
getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
```

[image]

Comment: please post your code about how yo define your actionBar and how you set the titles

Comment: I added my code snippet.